# .Net Core 2 EF core connection string problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

this is my appsettings.json

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Circolari": "Server=abcde;Database=Circolari;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
```

and this is my startup.cs

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
        Configuration = configuration;
        IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
 }


 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Circolari
        string connectoionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Circolari");
        services.AddDbContext<CircolariContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectoionString));
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

so when i do a query

```
using (CircolariContext db = new CircolariContext(new DbContextOptions<CircolariContext>()))
{
   List<Argomenti> listaArgomenti = db.Argomenti.ToList();
}
```

i have the problem: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

InvalidOperationException: A named connection string was used, but the name 'Circolari' was not found in the application's configuration. Note that named connection strings are only supported when using 'IConfiguration' and a service provider, such as in a typical ASP.NET Core application. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=850912 for more information.

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NamedConnectionStringResolverBase.ResolveConnectionString(string connectionString)

could someone help me please?

Comment: Are you sure your `appSettings.json` is being loaded? You've marked it as optional, so if `env.ContentRootPath` isn't the right folder, it won't be loaded. Try marking it as `optional: false` to see if it throws an exception.

Comment: Your example code for "so when I do a query" does not use dependency injection, is that the actual code generating the error?  I wonder how the error is getting the connection string name "Circolari" if so...

Comment: @John i think that the configuration is loaded because if  i put a breackpoint in ConfigureServices the string is readed, and with optional: false the error is still here

Comment: @Moho this is the actual code, the same i am writing in my little example for configuring ef core on .net core

Comment: Use `optional: false`.

Comment: `var connectoionString = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:Circolari");` is another way to get from configuration

Comment: @t-prisar if i use optional: false the problem persist

Comment: @mucciols Is there a chance that you're loading the wrong configuration file?

Comment: In ConfigureServices you have ˋUseSqlServer´ but in appsettings.json ˋServer=abcdé´?

Comment: @Moho with var connection = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:Circolari"); the problem persist

Comment: @Llazar yes, the 'abcde' is a replaced string that , the correct is in appsetting.json

Comment: @John i think that i am loading the correct configuration file because in 'ConfigureServices' string connectoionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Circolari"); give me the correction connection string

Comment: Why you are using the ˋIConfigureBuider´? What version of .Net core you are using?

Comment: @Llazar i use IConfigureBuilder because i think is the standard.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc v2.1.3
Microsoft.AspNetCore         v2.1.4

Comment: I think the IConfigureBuilder is used in .Net core 1.0. Check the docs for migration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @Llazar now my startup is empty and i iInject IConfiguration in Startup(IConfiguration configuration) but the problem is still there

Comment: But if you really are calling `new CircolariContext(new DbContextOptions<CircolariContext>())`, it doesn't use your configuration

Comment: Maybe you need to call directly without the string connectoionString

Comment: See the Exception ˋA named connection string was used,´.

Comment: @IvanStoev i am using this code  using (CircolariContext db = new CircolariContext())
                {
                    List<Argomenti> listaArgomenti = db.Argomenti.ToList();
                }

Comment: @Llazar yes, but ef does not find .... and i dont know why...

Comment: I think you need to call just the ˋCircularí´ connectionstring like ˋUseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Circolari")));´

Comment: @Llazar i don't want to modify this file because is generated by Scaffold-DbContext

Comment: ˋstring connectoionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Circolari");´ is generated by Scaffold-DbContext??

Comment: @Llazar, no but  
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Name=Circolari"); yes and i don't want to change code there

Answer (score 7):

**YouContextFile.cs** add this code

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
               // add IConfigurationRoot  to get connection string 
                IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), x => x.UseNetTopologySuite());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Adding this to my context has sorted my issue where I couldn't scaffold a new controller.

Answer (score 1):

> Modify startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DB_A6136B_MiGranCitaContext>(options =>
             options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MiGranCitaDB")));
```

> then add the controller using the option API CONTROLLER WITH ACTIONS USING ENTITY FRAMEWORK

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution to my problem:

now in asp.net core everything must be injected, so you can get yout db context via ServiceProvider (just like the compiler told me)

```
//this is the constructor
public EfGiacenzeRepo(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}


//this is the method
using (_aspContext = _serviceProvider.GetService<aspContext>())
{
    listaGiacenze = _aspContext.TabGiacenza.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same error message, and none of the solutions here solved the issue for me.

My problem was that in my DEV environment, I have multiple projects selected as startup projects.

When that is the case, it seems that Visual Studio does not know where to look for the appsettings.json file.

Temporarily switching to a single startup project solves this issue, so I do this when I need to rebuild the database models with Scaffold-DbContext.